# PHP Encrypt Data, Bash Decrypt it

Tags: php, bash, openssl, encryption

I am trying to come up with a way to have PHP encrypt a file. I used to just use a PHP system call to run a script that encoded the file:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -k $1 -in $2
```

Argument 1 was the password to use and argument 2 is the data. I then use a second script on a computer to de-crypt the file.

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/openssl aes-256-cbc -a -d -salt -k $1 -in $2
```

This method of encrypting will not work on a production host as the PHP system call is disabled. I also would prefer not the change the decode function if at all possible.

Is there a way to replicate the above encrypt function using only PHP?

Comment: The [Mcrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php) library does AES apparently ("Rijndael" is another name for AES).

Comment: Rijndael was the original name before it became "AES" as part of the NIST standardization process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated above in the comments padding is necessary to make this work. The function below will make a file that can be decrypted on the command line like this:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in test.txt
```

The test.txt file is created from the output of the ssl_encrypt function below.

```
function ssl_encrypt($pass, $data)
{
    // Set a random salt
    $salt = substr(md5(mt_rand(), true), 8);

    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $pad = $block - (strlen($data) % $block);

    $data = $data . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

    // Setup encryption parameters
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, "", MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, "");


    $key_len =  mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($td);
    $iv_len =  mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td);

    $total_len = $key_len + $iv_len;
    $salted = '';
    $dx = '';
    // Salt the key and iv
    while (strlen($salted) < $total_len)
    {
        $dx = md5($dx.$pass.$salt, true);
        $salted .= $dx;
    }
    $key = substr($salted,0,$key_len);
    $iv = substr($salted,$key_len,$iv_len);


    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
    $encrypted_data = mcrypt_generic($td, $data);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);


    return chunk_split(base64_encode('Salted__' . $salt . $encrypted_data),32,"\r\n");
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
$plainText = "Secret Message";
$password = "SecretPassword";
$test = ssl_encrypt($password, $plainText);
$file = fopen('test.txt', 'wb');
// Write the Base64 encrypted output to a file.
fwrite($file, $test);
fclose($file);
// Show the output on the screen
echo $test;
```

References: http://juan.boxfi.com/2010/03/16/write-openssl-files-in-php/

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [`mcyrpt_encrypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php):

```
string mcrypt_encrypt ( string $cipher , string $key , string $data , 
                        string $mode [, string $iv ] )
```

Set `$cipher` to `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` (AES-128), and `$mode` to `MCRYPT_MODE_CBC`.

Then use [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) to generate a base-64 encoded output (ie: what the `-a` option 
does).

---

openssl derives the key and IV as follows:

```
Key = MD5(Password + Salt)
IV  = MD5(Key + Password + Salt)
```

Where `Salt` is a 8 byte salt. With this in mind, I created simple `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` routines:

---

```
function ssl_encrypt($pass, $data) {

    $salt = substr(md5(mt_rand(), true), 8);

    $key = md5($pass . $salt, true);
    $iv = md5($key . $pass . $salt, true);

    $ct = mcrypt_encrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, 
                          MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    return base64_encode('Salted__' . $salt . $ct);
}

function ssl_decrypt($pass, $data) {

    $data = base64_decode($data);
    $salt = substr($data, 8, 8);
    $ct = substr($data, 16);

    $key = md5($pass . $salt, true);
    $iv = md5($key . $pass . $salt, true);

    $pt = mcrypt_decrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ct, 
                          MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    return $pt;
}
```

The parameter `$data` takes the string to be encrypted. If you want to encrypt a file, you'll have to get it via `file_get_contents()` or similar and then give that to the function.

Usage:

```
echo ssl_encrypt('super secret key', 'Hello World');
```

Generates something like (will change every time because of the random salt):

```
U2FsdGVkX18uygnq8bZYi6f62FzaeAnyB90U6v+Pyrk=
```

Comment: @GregS This *is* the `openssl enc` format. The IV is not saved, instead it is derived from the salt as I described.

Comment: This *should* work, but for some reason openssl is failing to decrypt some of the input generated by my `encrypt()` routine when it's saved to a file, even though my `decrypt()` routine can handle strings generated by both my `encrypt()` routine and openssl's enc just fine. This might have something to do with the way newlines at the end of the file are handled.

Comment: @Greg Well, if that were the case, shouldn't my `decrypt()` also fail?

Comment: @GregS That's the thing, my `decrypt()` works fine with `openssl enc` output

Comment: I confirm that PHP decrypt of openssl encrypt works but still had padding on the end. That gave me an idea so I added code to the PHP encrypt function to add it for the encrypt but I'm still getting "error reading input file" when trying to decrypt with openssl.

Comment: @NullUserException ఠ_ఠ
This is really close however does not work with the decode script above. For my simple test I copied and pasted the code above and then copied the output text to a file and ran decode.sh (listed above) when that is run a cryptic error is thrown. `140619014395712:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:536:`

Comment: @kaptk2 Yes, I've been getting that too. It's probably a padding issue.

Comment: apperently mcrypt_encrypt pads with zeros, whereas openssl used standard PKCS7 padding.

Comment: @NullUserException ఠ_ఠ It appears to be a chunking issue. OpenSSL expects the chunks to be in 32bytes. The PHP chunk_split function will do this for you combined with PKCS padding and the file is output correctly.

Comment: @GregS Also thanks for the tip on the padding. That really helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps PHP's [OpenSSL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) library?

Comment: One would think that would work. However I have been unsuccessful at getting PHP's implementation of OpenSSL to work with a "standard" install of OpenSSL.